# what does "sip sign green-light" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am non-native speaker.

I saw the ad 'sip sign green-light' of Smart water on WIRED. 
But I have no idea what the copy means.

Is there any connection between the copy and the product?

Comment: It's just an ad campaign of some water company. They are trying to positively associate the "sip" of their water with some other actions. Nothing more than that. It doesn't really have much to do with English language.

Answer (score 1):

'sip sign green-light isn't the only ad copy used for Smartwater's "Up, Up, Up" marketing campaign. Here are a few others:

- sip pitch fast track
- sip focus take two
- sip dash connect

From [this](http://www.usmagazine.com/celebrity-style/news/jennifer-aniston-smartwater-ad-photos-upupup-campaign-201596):

> Smartwater's director, Caroline Kibler, for one, hopes that the images
>   will inspire people to be just as ambitious as the leading lady.
>   "Success doesn't happen in a single moment. In the same way that
>   Smartwater is water inspired by the clouds, we want to inspire
>   consumers…to elevate their everyday journeys," she said. "Great things
>   happen little by little, sip by sip. Up, up, up!"

From this brief description I gather from this particular slogan, "sip sign green-light" three separate instructions:

1. **"Sip" the water**
2. **Wait for a "sign" (a good idea/insight from the *Smartwater*)**
3. **Then you have the "green-light" to go on that idea/insight**

The job of their marketing campaign is to make you want to feel more successful, smart or inspired. Put simply, *"Drink Smartwater to do things smarter."*

They also want you to be curious and ask questions, thus leading you to dwell longer on their brand, as you did here for yourself and anyone else thinking on this.

Comment: @Rathony he asked what the copy means, not the words. He obviously speaks English and is likely very capable of looking up the words without asking you.

Comment: If it's "Opinion-based" how in the world would he be able to look up this information on the Internet. You're digging yourself a hole my friend, quit while you're ahead.

Comment: I make my living through branding and marketing. I get paid for my imagination, and so do their marketers.

Comment: Don't you just hate it when people try o shoot down your answer, then delete their comment—slinking away into the darkness, and leaving your good rebuttals stranded?!

Comment: I think the answer from @justaguy better explains what you list as 2 and 3.  There is parallelism between the three verbs: sip, sign, green-light. All active, as opposed to the more passive objects you propose. But putting the ad in context with their other ads is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this is more about Aniston as the woman behind the camera in a business position. She sips the water, signs the document, and green lights the next film/commerical/deal into production. This is about her transition from actress to business professional and it is the water that will assist you in making those big decisions.